# To get a short name for data from a react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

here is my code

```
const { data , isLoading, ...} = useInfo();

console.log(data?.data.payload.info);
```

'useInfo' is react-query hook i made.
`data?.data.payload.info`is is too long..

i want to use data name with no deps

Is there a way to use it as below?

```
console.log(info) => returns data only i need
```

teach me the way and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructure the `info` property of `data.data.payload`.

```
const { info } = data?.data.payload;
```